# Parallel Dp-branes and force

Tags: string-theory, branes

While studying basic Dp-brane dynamics from [A. Giveon & D. Kutasov reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9802067), on page 24 they state the following

> Since Dp-branes are BPS saturated objects, parallel branes do not exert forces on each other.

It is not clear to me why this must be true even if the statement seems obvious. Why it is that the condition on BPS saturation implies the said statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two objects with an associated potential energy $V(x)$, where $x$ is the distance between the objects then the force attracting them is $V'(x)$. If the objects are stationary then there is no kinetic energy. Therefore, if you know that the energy $H = 0$ is a constant that does not depend on the distance between the objects, then you know that there is no attractive force.

**Edit:** Note that a BPS state has zero energy because it is annihilated by the supersymmetry operators

Comment: Yes, this is clear. But how does BPS saturation enter the game in this reasoning?

Comment: A BPS state has zero energy because it is annihilated by the supersymmetry operators

Comment: Ohhh yes, that makes sense. Thank you very much!